# Proper way to customize an InfoPath web-based form with CSS and Javascript

Tags: infopath

I need to add custom CSS and JavaScript to an InfoPath web-based form.

For which I am planning to export the source files and customize the view1.xsl file.

If I add the customizations in the header, they will be removed by InfoPath Designer next time I edit the form.

If I add the customizations in the body, some other developer may remove them.

My question is - what is the proper way to add customizations? Thank you!

Comment: My experience has been that if you need to do that (CSS and JS), then use a customized Newform.aspx page instead. It is significantly less frustrating than trying to beat InfoPath into submission.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't be sure where to start. Could you point me to a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page where your infopath is shown, add a script editor web part and there add your code or the url of css files. I've even add a visual web part to prefill infopath's fields with data (like last month salary) .